# How to pass props to a React Router route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-router, components

I'm trying to pass data from App to Home component but I don't know how in this situation.

In my App.js, I have firebase auth which holds email when logged in.
I need to pass this to Home component but I don't know how in this situation.I know how to pass data by doing somthing like `<Home user={user}>` this but not right now.

In where should I put passing data in code like this?

```
<Route exact  path="/" component={Home} />
```

I attached my code in CodeSandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-mestorf-8qbx9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

There are App.js  Home.js and Login.js

What i did in App.js is rendering pages and only to see pages when logged in. 
Login.js is logging in with firebase auth and finally in Home component, I want to print out user's email.

Can somebody give me clues or help me please?? I will be very thankful:))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass props into a react-router route you must use a slightly different syntax

```
<Route
  exact
  path='/'
  render={(props) => <Home {...props} auth={authState} />}
/>
```

In this case, `authState` would be your firebase user data. It could be a boolean, or any other data you want to pass in as a prop.

Then in your Home component you will receive the prop and can use it however you want:

```
function Home({auth}) {
  return (
    <div>
      {auth ? <h1>Logged In</h1> : <h1>Logged Out</h1>}
    </div>
  );
}
```